# LINK expected input to be a number but got the turtle (turtle 26) instead

Tags: netlogo

how can I assign a link to variable. there is a run time error in my code when it run this line

```
let link-who link node2-who this-one
```

node2-who and this-one are turtles.

and this is runtime error :

> LINK expected input to be a number but got the turtle (turtle 26)
>   instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure `link` takes the `who` numbers of two turtles and returns the link connecting them. You're getting that error because at least one of the inputs you're giving it is a turtle, not a `who` number.

Now, that said, I recommend avoiding using `who` numbers at all (except in very special circumstances). Instead, if you want to get the link between the current turtle and some other turtle, you can do

`link-with other-turtle`

where `other-turtle` is the other turtle (it would probably be called something like `node2` in your case).

Comment: I agree with everything that Bryan says. But note that if it's really true that "node2-who and this-one are turtles" (and not who numbers of turtles), then 1) your variable names are confusingly chosen, and 2) correct code for getting the link between them would be `[link-with node2-who] of this-one` (substituting `link-to` or `link-from` for `link-with` if your links are directed).